# Summation of the minimum of two options

Tags: summation, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to figure out how to sum a minimum functions, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \min \Bigl( m - 2i, \lfloor\frac{n-2j}{2}\rfloor\Bigr)$$

and

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor} \min \Bigl( m - 2i - 1, \lfloor\frac{n-2j-1}{2}\rfloor\Bigr)$$

And I have no idea how to do this sum without specifying $m$ and $n$. Are there any resources that offer a tutorial on doing this type of sum?

Thank you

Comment: So you want a closed formula for this sum (in terms of $m$ and $n$)?

Comment: Either a closed formula, or a resource that offers guidance in summing these types of expressions

Comment: What would a resource look like that *wouldn't* be a closed formula? If you want something like a computer program to do it, that would be fairly trivial to implement (although wouldn't help too much finding a closed formula).

Comment: I haven't worked with problems like this, but I'd imagine the following might be a good idea. Let $A_{m,n} = [0,\dots,\lfloor m/2\rfloor]\times [0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor]$ be the set that the indicies $(i,j)$ are defined on. We want to find a way to break $A_{m,n} = A_1\sqcup A_2$ where $A_2$ is the set of all indices such that the $\min(a,b) = a$, and $A_2$ are the other ones. This would let you "remove" the min from the sum, which would probably help a lot.

This will boil down to trying to characterize for what $(i,j)$ the following holds: $m-2i \leq \lfloor(n/2)-j\rfloor$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a general way to characterize $A_1$ from this.  Trying to do this is where I would personally start though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  calculate the first sum with even $m$ and $n$. The other cases can be treated similarly.

> The following is valid for non-negative even integers $m=2M, n=2N$.
>   \begin{align*}
> &\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\min\left\{m-2i,\left\lfloor\frac{n-2j}{2}\right\rfloor\right\}\\
> &=\left\{
> \begin{array}{lr}
> \frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(6N-4M+1)\qquad&\quad M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\\\\
> \frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(4M+5)\\
> \quad+\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(3N-4\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)\qquad&\quad \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor<M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\\\\
> \frac{1}{6}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor(\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+1)(4\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+5)\\
> \quad+\left(M-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)\\
> \quad+\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(3N-4\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)\qquad&\quad M>\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{align*}

We obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\min\left\{m-2i,\left\lfloor\frac{n-2j}{2}\right\rfloor\right\}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^N\min\left\{2(M-i),N-j\right\}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^N\min\left\{2i,j\right\}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]+\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we substitute $m=2M$ and $n=2N$ and get rid of the floor symbols.
- In (2) we exchange the order of summation $i\to M-i, j\to N-j$ and we also let the indices start with $1$ since $i=0$ and $j=0$ does not contribute anything.
- In (3) we sum up the inner sum dependent on  the index $i$ of the outer sum and use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* $[[P]]$ to prevent overcounting.

> We continue summing the left sum of (3) by splitting it into two cases and using *[power summation formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)*.
>
> - **$M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]&=\sum_{i=1}^M\frac{1}{2}(2i)(2i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^M(2i^2+i)\\
> &=2\cdot\frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(2M+1)+\frac{1}{2}M(M+1)\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(4M+5)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> - **$M> \left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
>   We split the left sum of (3) into two sums, use the result (4) and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M&\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor}\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j
> +\sum_{i={\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor}+1}^M\sum_{j=1}^Nj\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(4\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+5\right)
> +\left(M-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> Next we calculate the right sum of (3) again by splitting it into two cases and using *[power summation formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)*.
>
> - **$M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i&=\sum_{i=1}^M2i(N-2i)=2N\sum_{i=1}^Mi-4\sum_{i=1}^Mi^2\\
> &=NM(M+1)-\frac{2}{3}M(M+1)(2M+1)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3}M(M+1)(3N-4M-2)\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> - **$M> \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
>   We use the result (6) and obtain
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i&=\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\sum_{i=2i+1}^N2i\\
>   &=\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(3N-4\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)\tag{7}
>   \end{align*}

Now it's time to harvest. We collect the results (4) to (7) and put them into the intermediate result (3).

> - **$M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
>   We obtain from (4) and (6)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M&\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]+\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(4M+5)+\frac{1}{3}M(M+1)(3N-4M-2)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(6N-4M+1)}
> \end{align*}
>
> - **$ \left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor<M\leq \left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
>   We obtain from (4) and (7)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M&\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]+\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}M(M+1)(4M+5)}\\
> &\,\,\qquad\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(3N-4\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)}
> \end{align*}
>
> - **$M> \left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor$**
>
>   We obtain from (5) and (7)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^M&\sum_{j=1}^{2i}j[[j\leq N]]+\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=2i+1}^{N}2i\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(4\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor+5\right)
> +\left(M-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(3N-4\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

**Note:** The results might be simplified by using
\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad N\equiv 1(2)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad n\equiv 2(4)\\
\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1=\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad N\equiv 0(2)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad n\equiv 0(4)\\
\end{align*}

**Hint:** Chapter 3 in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik
contains a thorough introduction of floor and ceiling functions.